# ¿Cómo guardar datos en un esquema de PostgreSQL con Django?

Tags: base-de-datos, django, postgresql, djangorestframework

estoy haciendo un proyecto con angular y Django, cree un nuevo esquema **cli1** en la base de datos  y quiero guardar la información allí, pero no se como hacer para que se valla directamente a las tablas de ese esquema, ya que por defecto se me guardan el las tablas del esquema **publico(public)**.

**base de datos y esquemas**

[image]

fragmento del archivo **settings.py** donde me conecto a ala base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las bases de datos pueden tener cualquier alias que elija. Sin embargo, el alias default tiene un significado especial. Django usa la base de datos con el alias de default cuando no se ha seleccionado ninguna otra base de datos.

Por ejemplo:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'users': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'superS3cret'
    }
}
```

Si el concepto de defaultbase de datos no tiene sentido en el contexto de su proyecto, debe tener cuidado de especificar siempre la base de datos que desea utilizar. Django requiere que defaultse defina una entrada de base de datos, pero el diccionario de parámetros se puede dejar en blanco si no se va a utilizar.

Puedes consultar mas información en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/).

---

#### Actualización:

**Según lo que comentas he visto esto en el foro en ingles:**

Debido a que Django no admite esquemas de base de datos de PostgreSQL listos para usar, para que esto funcione, use un [enrutador de base de datos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers)

Creé una base de datos de prueba para probar esto, así es como se reproduce. Cree una base de datos de prueba con `psql`:

```
CREATE USER tester WITH PASSWORD 'lol so easy';
CREATE DATABASE multi_schema_db WITH OWNER tester;
CREATE SCHEMA sampleSchema AUTHORIZATION tester;
CREATE TABLE sampleSchema.my_samples (
  id          INTEGER   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  description CHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Agregue los esquemas a la configuración como diferentes conexiones de base de datos, recuerde agregar `HOST` para evitar el error `"Error de autenticación de pares"`.

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=django,public'
        },
        'NAME': 'multi_schema_db',
        'USER': 'tester',
        'PASSWORD': 'lol so easy',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    
    },
    
    'sampleSchema': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=sampleSchema,public'
        },
        'NAME': 'multi_schema_db',
        'USER': 'tester',
        'PASSWORD': 'lol so easy',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    },
}
```

A continuación, cree el modelo `MySamplemodelo`:

```py
from django.db import models

class MySample(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_samples'
```

Cree un enrutador de base de datos para dirigir todas las consultas relacionadas con la muestra a la base de datos de muestra:

```py
from database_test.models import MySample

ROUTED_MODELS = [MySample]

class MyDBRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model in ROUTED_MODELS:
            return 'sampleSchema'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model in ROUTED_MODELS:
            return 'sampleSchema'
        return None
```

Básicamente, el enrutador enturará todos los modelos especificados en `ROUTED_MODELS` a la conexión de la base de datos `sampleSchema` y devolverá `None` para todos los demás modelos. Esto los enturará a la conexión `default` de la base de datos.

Finalmente agregue el enrutador a su archivo `settings.py`:

```py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ('database_test.db_router.MyDBRouter',)
```

Y ahora, al hacer una consulta para el `MySamplemodelo`, obtendrá datos del `sampleSchema`.

Te dejo por [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819748/django-and-postgresql-schemas) el enlace del post.

Comment: buenas, no es que quiera usar otra base de datos, quiero usar otro esquema en la misma base de datos, es decir la base de datos se llama *ARTICULOSCLIENTES* y dentro tengo el esquema public(el cual viene por defecto al crear la base de datos) y el esquema *cli1* que fue el que yo cree y hay es donde quiero guardar la información, entonces quiero saber como hago que se guarde en ese esquema en especifico

Answer (score 0):

```
A mi me sirvio solamente con definir los esquemas 

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'default',
        'USER': 'default',
        'PASSWORD': 'default',
        'HOST': 'localhost',  # O la dirección del servidor de la base de datos
        'PORT': 'default',     
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'options': '-c- search_path=public,esquema2,esquema3' 
                }
    }
}

en mi clase 
class ejemplo(models.Model):
    #atributos

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'esquema2\".\"mitabla'
```